# How to change z index of components in React?

Tags: reactjs

I forked the Keeper app project from Angela Yu's course on Udemy and made some modifications. Here is the link: https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-app-part-2-completed-forked-9zks1?file=/src/components/Note.js

I wanted to be able to move the notes around the canvas, and while I was able to do that, I'm having a problem with the stacking of the notes. I want the selected note to be on top of all the other notes. I've tried tinkering with the z-index value by creating a useRef called noteRef and typing:

```
noteRef.current.style.zIndex = 9999
```

inside the handleOnClick function, which is called during onMouseDown. However, it doesn't really do anything. I tried having that and then typing

```
noteRef.current.style.zIndex = 1
```

inside the handleOnUp function, and while I was able to have the selected note on top of the others while moving, obviously it just goes right back below the notes when I release the mouse.

I've also tried using useEffect but it also didn't change anything. I was wondering if there is a way to access functions from the App component (where the note components reside).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDITED
[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/keeper-app-part-2-completed-forked-2l60v?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/components/Note.js) is my example code sandbox.

How about managing notes` z-index with state in parent component?

In below's my example, i used `useState` in `App` component and made `stackNote` function for handling child component's style.

```js
function App () {
  const [zIndex, setZindex] = useState(1);
  const stackNote = (ref) => {
    ref.current.style.zIndex = zIndex;
    setZindex((zIndex) => zIndex + 1);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Header />
      {notes.map((noteItem) => (
        <Note
          stackNote={stackNote}
          key={noteItem.key}
          title={noteItem.title}
          content={noteItem.content}
        />
      ))}
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Then, in the `Note` component, just call `stackNote` with `noteRef` in your `handleOnClick`.

```js
function handleOnClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    props.stackNote(noteRef);
    offsetX = e.pageX - notePos.x;
    offsetY = e.pageY - notePos.y;

    console.log("Mouse is clicked!");
    document.addEventListener("mousemove", handleOnMove);
    document.addEventListener("mouseup", handleOnUp);
  }
```

And don't forget should erase previous codes something like `noteRef.current.style.zIndex = ...`

Although `ref` existed in the original code, so i used as it is, but it doesn't seem necessary to use it.

Comment: This worked! Thanks.. This was what I was looking for, being able to pass values back to the parent component... nice!

Comment: @NumpyNoob Im glad to hear that :)